# Google drive on windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, google

Is it possible to install Google drive on windows 2003? When I try to install **googledrivesync.exe** I get the following error:-

[image: Error message]

Click the link takes me [here](http://support.google.com/installer/bin/static.py?hl=en&os=5.2&sp=Service%20Pack%202&iid=%7B8DCC6370-82EE-B5C7-6941-89B03D7C6771%7D&m=1&rd=1&source=gethelp&page=article_group.cs&ec.0=0x80040902&app.0=%7B3C122445-AECE-4309-90B7-85A6AEF42AC0%7D&ex.0=1603&guver=1.3.21.111), which to be honest doesn't tell me much. Looked at Google help and I can't see a systems requirements page.

I don't have Chrome installed, not sure if this casues the problem or not.

Comment: Thanks for -1 its great to know why this is a bad question.

Comment: This is off-topic, because it's not related to system administration, but to the compatibility of a specific application with a specific OS (which just by chance happens to be a server OS).

Comment: So where do I go to ask a question like this

Comment: http://superuser.com

Comment: So can this get migrated then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, looking at [google groups](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/U3wAfNRpBQg) I needed to download and install

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

OK the post mentions XP but I checked and this redist package wasn't installed on the server.

Answer (score 2):

The system requirements are listed [here](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=2375082).  There are no server OSes explicitly listed, but there is an ambiguous *Windows* OS listed under the **Windows** section.